# Matrices Representation of Linear Equation AX=B

Tags: matrices

Hi I am new To Latex and trying To write a paper. Please provide me with how to write in latex for below matrix ?

[image]

I was only able to do this:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
\hdotsfor{5} 
x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far. Please also tell us if you're familiar with (a) the distinction between text and math mode and (b) the `amsmath` package and its matrix-like environments, e.g., `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `vmatrix`, etc.

Comment: No sir i dont know . But yes i have tried this \[
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
    \hdotsfor{5} \\
    x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

Comment: You appear to be familiar with the `bmatrix` environment. Is something not working for you?

Answer (score 5):

Echoing the sentiment expressed by @PrzemysławScherwentke, I also hope that you're not looking to reproduce *exactly* the rather uninspired look of the matrices shown in the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots & \dots  \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \dots \\ x_n 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,n+1} \\ a_{2,n+1} \\ \dots \\ a_{n,n+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\medskip

\[
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt} % default value: 0.4pt
\left[ \mkern1mu \begin{array}{@{}ccccc|c@{}}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1n} & a_{1,n+1} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2n} & a_{2,n+1} \\
\dots  & \dots  & \dots  & \dots & \dots  & \dots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn} & a_{n,n+1} 
\end{array} \mkern1mu \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach for the vertical line. You may add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

The advantage of this is that you can treat your matrix as a `table` or `array`, by setting the parameters `l`, `c` and/or `r` between brackets to align the entries. The original idea is from [this post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/).

I used the matrix you were working on. The complete code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}[ccccc|c]
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \cdots & x_{1n} & a_{1,n+1} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \cdots & x_{2n} & a_{2,n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots    \\
x_{d1} & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \cdots & x_{dn} & a_{d,n+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few additional comments. To me the column vector with the `1,n+1` subscripts is unintuitive as a labeling for the column vector **b**. I also find it ugly. You might consider renaming as in the example here:

[image]

I prefer using `vdots` and `ddots`. Then the augmented matrix looks like this:

[image]

You can add the vertical line to this matrix as others have described if you wish. When I teach Linear Algebra, I use this formatting. Here's the code:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\ \vdots\\b_n
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} & b_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_n
\end{bmatrix}    
\]
```

Comment: very useful, thankyou.

Comment: No the first part is not giving any equation of matrices. Please check again.